# Hacer tabla editable

Tags: php, jquery

Quiero que mi tabla tenga celdas editables y así mismo sean guardadas en la base de datos, pero en el codigo que tengo no me funciona para editar.

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "kenworth";
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname) or die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
if (mysqli_connect_error()) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());
    exit();
}

$input = filter_input_array(INPUT_POST);
if ($input['action'] == 'edit') {
    $update_field='';
    if (isset($input['Sucursal'])) {
        $update_field.= "Sucursal='".$input['Sucursal']."'";        
    } else if (isset($input['nombre'])) {
        $update_field.= "nombre='".$input['nombre']."'";
    } else if (isset($input['service_tag'])) {
        $update_field.= "service_tag='".$input['service_tag']."'";
    } else if (isset($input['Departamento'])) {
        $update_field.= "Departamento='".$input['Departamento']."'";
    } else if (isset($input['Marca'])) {
        $update_field.= "Marca='".$input['Marca']."'";
    } else if (isset($input['Modelo'])) {
        $update_field.= "Modelo='".$input['Modelo']."'";
    } else if (isset($input['Office'])) {
        $update_field.= "Office='".$input['Office']."'";
    } else if (isset($input['Discio_duro'])) {
        $update_field.= "Discio_duro='".$input['Discio_duro']."'";
    } else if (isset($input['ram'])) {
        $update_field.= "ram='".$input['ram']."'";
    } else if (isset($input['Unidad'])) {
        $update_field.= "Unidad='".$input['Unidad']."'";
    } else if (isset($input['Sistema_operativo'])) {
        $update_field.= "Sistema_operativo='".$input['Sistema_operativo']."'";
    } else if (isset($input['Lic_Win'])) {
        $update_field.= "Lic_Win='".$input['Lic_Win']."'";
    } else if (isset($input['Monitor'])) {
        $update_field.= "Monitor='".$input['Monitor']."'";
    } else if (isset($input['Nu_serie_mon'])) {
        $update_field.= "Nu_serie_mon='".$input['Nu_serie_mon']."'";
    } else if (isset($input['mouse'])) {
        $update_field.= "mouse='".$input['mouse']."'";
    } else if (isset($input['teclado'])) {
        $update_field.= "teclado='".$input['teclado']."'";
    }
    if ($update_field && $input['Sucursal']) {
        $sql_query = "UPDATE equipo SET $update_field where Sucursal='" . $input['Sucursal'] . "'";
        mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query) or die("database error:". mysqli_error($conn));
    }
}
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <title>Tabla editable</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <link href = "//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/css/bootstrap-editable.css" rel = "hoja de estilo" /> <script src = "/ /cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/x-editable/1.5.0/bootstrap3-editable/js/bootstrap-editable.min.js " > </script>  


</head>
<body style="background:#9e9e9e;color:#cdcdcd;">
 <div class="container home">
  <h2>Ejemplo tabla editable</h2>
  <table id="data_table" class="table table-striped" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Sucursal</th>
            <th>Usuario</th>
            <th>Service Tag</th>
            <th>Departamento</th>
            <th>Marca</th>
            <th>Modelo</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>DD</th>
            <th>Ram</th>
            <th>Unidad</th>
            <th>S.O.</th>
            <th>Lic.Windows</th>
            <th>Monitor</th>
            <th>No Serie Monitor</th>
            <th>Mouse</th>
            <th>Teclado</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php
        $sql_query= "SELECT Sucursal, nombre, service_tag, Departamento, Marca, Modelo, Office, Discio_duro, ram, Unidad, Sistema_operativo, Lic_Win, Monitor, Nu_serie_mon, mouse, teclado from equipo";
        $resultset = mysqli_query($conn, $sql_query) or die ("error base de datos:". mysqli_error($conn));
        while ( $equipo = mysqli_fetch_assoc($resultset) ) {
        ?>

        <tr>
        <td><?php echo $equipo ['Sucursal']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $equipo ['nombre']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $equipo ['service_tag']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $equipo ['Departamento']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $equipo ['Marca']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $equipo ['Modelo']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $equipo ['Office']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $equipo ['Discio_duro']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $equipo ['ram']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $equipo ['Unidad']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $equipo ['Sistema_operativo']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $equipo ['Lic_Win']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $equipo ['Monitor']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $equipo ['Nu_serie_mon']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $equipo ['mouse']; ?></td>
        <td><?php echo $equipo ['teclado']; ?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
  </table>
 </div>
 <style>
 table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  color: black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: scroll;
  overflow: auto;
}

td, th {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}

tr:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: #757575;
}
</style>
 <script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#data_table").Tabledit({
        deleteButton: false,
        editButton: false,
        columns: {
            editable: [[1, 'Sucursal'], [2, 'nombre'], [3, 'service_tag'], [4, 'Departamento'], [5, 'Marca'], [6, 'Modelo'], [7, 'Office'], [8, 'Discio_duro'], [9, 'ram'], [10, 'Unidad'], [11, 'Sistema_operativo'], [12, 'Lic_Win'], [13, 'Monitor'], [14, 'Nu_serie_mon'], [15, 'monitor'], [16, 'teclado']]
        },
    });

});



 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
        <script src="static/js/jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="static/js/materialize-01.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/index.js"></script>
        <script src="./js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
        <script src="js/materialize.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!

Comment: Así a simple vista, estás repitiendo la carga de scripts como el de bootstrap,Córdoba etc. Carga solo una vez los scripts. También veo que estás usando dos librerías para editar la tabla, y seguramente una esté entrando en conflicto con la otra. Yo suelo usar tabledit para editar en línea las tablas y va bastante bien y tú estás cargando x-editable y tabledit, comienza por simplificar.